# News-feed collection and request design with Firestore

Tags: firebase, database-design, google-cloud-firestore

**For a news-feed comprised of posts as shown in the attached image, what is the best way to load the user-name and user-pic corresponding to each post when working with Firestore?**

[image]

**Firestore Collections:**

```
user
- userId 
- userName
- userPic

post
- postContent
- postDate
- userId // refers to the userId of a user stored in the users collection
```

**With Firestore, how do I load say the latest 10 posts - with the respective user-name and user-pic attached to it - in the most efficient way?**

Solutions I considered that won't work for me:

- *Load all user-data on app startup, then manually compare the user-id stored in the posts to the loaded users to get the user-details.* Why not? Too many users to load them all upfront!
- *Save the user-name and user-pic in the post-document when publishing the post to Firestore.* Why not? Because the user-name and/or user-pic could change after the post has been published!
- *Fetch the posts from Firestore, then in the app, for each individual post, fetch the corresponding user-data from Firestore based on user-id.* Why not? A lot of additional requests to Firestore. For example, if I wanted to load 10 posts, it would be one request for the 10 posts, plus another 10 requests to get each user by id, making a total of 11 requests.

**Is there a way to have Firestore combine the user-data with the posts on its end, before sending me the result? (like one would do in an actual DBMS)**

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8D9XnnjFGMs

Answer (score 0):

You're guessing right, in case of first two situations but the third case can solve your problem. Since in Cloud Firestore the `Reference` is a [supported data types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types), you can take advantage of this feature:

> projects/[PROJECT_ID]/databases/[DATABASE_ID]/documents/[DOCUMENT_PATH]

So you can hold a reference to the user object, so you can get its details very easily. It's true that you need an extra read but this is the easiest way I can think of so you can achieve what you want.

You can also denormalize data, by adding the user object as a property of your post object but this implies am extra update, to all user objects in case the user is changing the name. So in this case you have too more extra write operations. This practice is called `denormalization` and is a common practice when it comes to Firebase. For a better understanding, i recomand you see this video, [Denormalization is normal with the Firebase Database](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKqXSZLLnHA). It is for Firebase realtime database but same rules apply to Cloud Firestore. So, how much duplication data versus extra database calls is optimal for you, depends on the use-case of you app and your needs and your willingness to let go of the "Single Point of Definition mindset".